# How can I search for matches in the table and display them in a list in one cell using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are 2 sheets per page. on one there is a list of products and on the second there are places where these products can be found

How do I display all the places where items can be found on 1 sheet in column B? For example, in B2, write Shop1, Shop3 (apples, judging by the 2nd sheet, are there) Potentially, there will be more than 20 "shopes" on the second sheet. How do I parse the entire sheet?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SYy5qPKPiSsBfLHSvdH1PsB17mxFvv7YhLpk4nw3x_I/edit#gid=1905240203

tryed to use google function =TRIM(IF(COUNTIF('Base1'!$A:$B,A2),'Base1'!$A$1&" ","")&IF(COUNTIF('Base1'!$D:$E,A2),'Base1'!$D$1&" ","")&IF(COUNTIF('Base1'!$G:$H,A2),'Base1'!$G$1&" ",""))  but it's hard to scale

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561233/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of custom function that will find the shops.  This may be able to be done with a =QUERY() but I'm not that good at it and had no success.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function MYQUERY(product) {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Base1");
    let products = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let shops = []
    for( let i=2; i<products.length; i++ ) {
      let row = products[i];
      for( let j=0; j<row.length; j+=3 ) {
        if( row[j] === product ) {
          shops.push(products[0][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    if( shops.length === 0 ) throw "Product ["+product+"] not found!";
    return shops.sort().join();
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)
- [Array.length](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp#mark_length)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Array.sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)
- [Array.join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)
- [Error handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: i will save, looks amazing will try to use, how i can add more sheets to scan in this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to the idea of solving this with a formula, here's a possbile solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   MAP(A2:A;LAMBDA(p;
     IF(p="";;
        TEXTJOIN(", ";1;
           IF(COUNTIF(p;Base1!A3:ZZZ);
              SCAN(;Base1!A1:1;
                LAMBDA(a;c;IF(c="";a;c)));))))))
```

[image]

This formula is designed to work even if you add more columns to the 'Base' sheet or more rows to the 'Product' sheet.

Comment: looks great, how can i add new sheets to scan in this formula?

Comment: @IvanIsaev try to replace `Base1!A3:ZZZ` with `HSTACK(Base1!A3:ZZZ,Base2!A3:ZZZ)` and `Base1!A1:1` with `HSTACK(Base1!A1:1,Base2!A1:1)`